# Installing Ruby on Mac OS X

Tags: osx, ruby

I had *ruby* installed in `/usr/local/bin/` but it was outdated, so I installed newer version using `brew`. Now I have two installations of *ruby* in different dirs. Should I remove one? And how do I update pre-shipped ruby to the latest version?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [rvm](https://rvm.io/). This allows you to easily install a good ruby setup into your home directory. (In this case the outdated system rubies are not needed anymore.)